# Labelled Sections xamarin android that it don't run on xamarin android new version

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

```
public class ListItemCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
        where T : IHasLabel, IComparable<T>
    {
```

Errors: 
Error CS0703: Inconsistent accessibility: constraint type ....IHasLabel' is less accessible than ....ListItemCollection' (CS0703)

```html
public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
   base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
   /*
   var items = new string[] { "Rock","Country", "Dance" };


   lst = View.FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.lstGenres);
 
   lst.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Activity, Resource.Layout.textViewItems,Resource.Id.textviewItems, items);
   //lst = View.FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.lst_genre);

   //lst.SetAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.Activity, Resource.Layout.GenerFragment, items));


   lst.ItemClick+= delegate(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) {};*/

   var data = new ListItemCollection<ListItemValue> () {
    new ListItemValue ("Babbage"),
    new ListItemValue ("Boole"),
    new ListItemValue ("Berners-Lee"),
    new ListItemValue ("Atanasoff"),
    new ListItemValue ("Allen"),
    new ListItemValue ("Cormack"),
    new ListItemValue ("Cray"),
    new ListItemValue ("Dijkstra"),
    new ListItemValue ("Dix"),
    new ListItemValue ("Dewey"),
    new ListItemValue ("Erdos"),
   };

   var sortedContacts = data.GetSortedData ();
   var adapter = CreateAdapter (sortedContacts);
   ListAdapter = adapter;

  }

  SeparatedListAdapter CreateAdapter<T> (Dictionary<string, List<T>> sortedObjects)
   where T : IHasLabel, IComparable<T>
  {
   var adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter (this);
   foreach (var e in sortedObjects.OrderBy (de => de.Key)) {
    var label   = e.Key;
    var section = e.Value;
    adapter.AddSection (label, new ArrayAdapter<T> (this, Resource.Layout.lstGenres, section));
   }
   return adapter;
  }
```

ListAdapter = adapter;-> the name listadapter does not exist in the current context.

var adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter (this);-> the best overloaded method match for ....SeparatedListAdapter(android.content.context) has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

Just looked it up, someone forgot to add public...

```
namespace TablesAndCellStyles
{
    interface IHasLabel
    {
        string Label {get;}
    }
}
```

Not quite sure what your question is, use your own IHasLabel interface.

Comment: after I add public and show 6 errors . I will update code